# How my bot can ask to users or bot need reply from users to send message intelegraf node.js bot?

Tags: node.js, telegraf.js

```
bot.command("greeting", (ctx) => ctx.reply("Hello users, what's your name?");

ctx.reply("Hello Alex nice to meet you!")
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter which social bot you are using (viber, telegram, telegraf etc) it requires user to be subscribed on its incoming list and then you will be able to use `ctx.message.chat.id` to send message on specific registered user.

**telegraf** example:

```
bot.on('text', (ctx) => {
  // Explicit usage
  ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.message.chat.id, `Hello ${ctx.state.role}`)

  // Using context shortcut
  ctx.reply(`Hello ${ctx.state.role}`)
})
```

Moreover if there is a first time a user is sends a word to bot, there is a need to do the following.

```
bot.hears('/Hi', (ctx)=> ctx.reply('Hello ' + getName(ctx.message.from))

function getName(user) {
    return user.first_name || user.last_name;
}
```

If the bot receives a "Hi" it will reply with "Hello -user name-"